# Conditionally set attribute on component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

For my `Overlay` I am trying to only set the `height: 'auto'` when the screen width is 320 pixels wide.

Can anyone help?

```
    const windowWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: [
        {
          padding: 0,
        },
        windowWidth === 320 && { height: "auto" },
      ],...

  return (
    <Overlay
      isVisible={modalVisible}
      overlayStyle={styles.container}
      overlayBackgroundColor="#fff"
    >
```

Comment: Seems like you would be better off importing a stylesheet for the component with media queries.

Comment: Have u tried to use Media Queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
 const newStyle = windowWidth === 320 ? { height: "auto"} : {};
  const containerStyle = [
        {
          padding: 0,
        },
        newStyle
      ] 

  return (
    <Overlay
      isVisible={modalVisible}
      overlayStyle={containerStyle}
      overlayBackgroundColor="#fff"
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work. You can just spread the styles and add whatever property you want straight into the component props.

This is not going to be responsive, though. In that case, go towards media queries.

```
    const windowWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: [
        {
          padding: 0,
        },
     ],...

  return (
    <Overlay
      isVisible={modalVisible}
      overlayStyle={{...styles.container,height: windowWidth === 320 &&  "auto" }}
      overlayBackgroundColor="#fff"
    >
```